# SQL Update using internal data in the update

Tags: mysql, sql

Typically when you do an Update in SQL you have a syntax that looks like this:

UPDATE `table` SET `fieldname_a`= xxxx WHERE 'fieldname_b' = yyyy

My question is. How do I use the data in fieldname_c as the value for xxxx ?  So that if fieldname_b is yyyy I essentially copy the value from fieldname_c into fieldname_a ?

Thanks.

Comment: just do as `fieldname_a= fieldname_c`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to do an inner join, on the table itself... and accessing the aliased table's column, something like the following;

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname_a= xxxx
    INNER JOIN TABLE AS T ON T.[id] = id
WHERE 'fieldname_b' = T.fieldname_C
```

If it's straightforward were you don't need to join on the table itself, just put the fieldname_c in the where clause.

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname_a= xxxx WHERE fieldname_a = fieldname_C
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

UPDATE table SET fieldname_a = fieldname_c WHERE 'fieldname_b' = yyyy

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If fieldname_c is in the same table of fieldname_a:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname_a = fieldname_c WHERE fieldname_b = yyyy
```

If they are on different tables, supposing there is a relation between table1.fieldname_b and 
table2.fieldname_d

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.fieldname_a = table2.fieldname_c WHERE table1.fieldname_b  = table2.fieldname_d
```